# Using 2 htmlwidgets in 1 R-Shiny Application

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am working on creating widgets to work with specific D3 visualizations. I have successfully created both of the widgets I want to use. However, when I use these two widgets in the same `R-Shiny` application, only the first widget used has the `CSS` file added to the source code. The second widget called has its `CSS` left off. Resulting in some odd looking visualizations.

How can I work around this?

I call `HEBOutput()` and `CITOutput()` - my two functions. Thus, `HEBcss.css` is put into the source code, but `CITcss.css` is not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As noted by @pops Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The SO community will probably need to see some code to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not having a coding issue (no errors, bugs, etc) - the issue is that whichever widget is called first, only that CSS file is included in the source code. The second widget's CSS is ignored. I have no code to show for this.